# How to disable deprecation warnings for C/C++ compiler globally in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I want to have deprecation warnings(C4996, the ones caused by calling functions like strcpy) disabled by default in all C/C++ projects in Visual Studio 2019.

There are several ways on the internet on how to do it, but they are all on a per-project basis, the most straightforward way is to add _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS to the preprocessor definitions. But I want to achieve this effect automatically, without having to fiddle with the project setting each time I make a new project.

I know there must be a way. I don't care how "hacky" the method is. Using the safe variants of the functions isn't an option for me.

Comment: If there is a "way" that someone else has already fathomed, it's probably just a block of `#define` statements to copy and paste into your code.

Comment: By not using Visual C? What could be easier than adding the definitions to the source code?

Comment: Suck it up. You can't have *that* many projects for `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` addition to be that much of a headache? It's how the toolset works I'm afraid.

Comment: `Using the safe variants of the functions isn't an option for me.` care to elaborate?

Comment: They aren't all safer - because it is widely misunderstood how to use them. Such as the even more dangerous `scanf_s` when using `%c` and `%s` and `%[]`

Comment: I sympathize with you. When I was working with VS, I had a check list of about 10 things I needed to do every time I created a new project. _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS was definitely on the list.

Comment: My standard definitions are `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` and `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE` and `#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE` (and `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES`). I use a standard framework that contains them. Extra work: NULL.

Comment: @WeatherVane doing nothing after setting it up once is the easiest. Also definitions are not an option for me either.

Comment: @SergeyA I'm doing school projects and I'm obligated to have the code portable and use certain standard libraries.

Comment: @LightningShock The `#define` statements won't break compatibility with other compilers

Comment: It is easier to start from *somewhere* rather than retyping everything. Mine has those `#define` definitions and a list of `#include` files. It's easier to remove those not needed than to keep typing them in in every project, and the task is no different with those definitions as well as the `#include` headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create custom project templates in Visual Studio, so you should be able to create one of these with whatever `#defines` you want pre-configured in the properties page.

MS documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2019) and a guy called Srinivasa Rao Dhulipalla has blogged about it [here](https://www.ecanarys.com/Blogs/ArticleID/180/Create-custom-project-templates-in-Visual-Studio)

Comment: This one does it for me, thanks, but instead I just added my preprocessor definition on an empty C++ project and saved it as a template and it works wonders!